# bezierPathWithRoundedRect: gives bad result on retina screen

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, rounding, uibezierpath

I used a method to get rounded pictures on my iOS app which work perfectly fine on iphone 3. My problem is that as soon as I try it on iphone 4 or above, the pictures get a bad quality.

Is there any way, I can turn my code around to get high res rounded picture?

```
-(void) setRoundedView:(UIImageView *)imageView picture: (UIImage *)picture toDiameter:(float)newSize{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);

[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:imageView.bounds
                            cornerRadius:100.0] addClip];

CGRect frame=imageView.bounds;
frame.size.width=newSize;
frame.size.height=newSize;
[picture drawInRect:frame];

imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is how you're defining your image context. You are specifying a 1.0 scale, but on retina screens that should be 2.0.

Instead you can use 0.0 to default to native quality:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
```